# How to remove text from Barcode image

Tags: java, barcode

I have written a code which can generate a bar-code with respect to         **String codeText = "1104006";** and also can read data from that bar-code. But the problem is, while generating a bar-code below the bar-code it also write the text (**codeText**). How can I remove the human readable text, circled red in example?

[image: example output with human readable circled in red]

```
public class Main {

    private static String strBarFolder = ("C:\\Users\\Jobayer__\\Desktop\\");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String codeText = "1104006";
        String strImageFile = ("barcode.jpg");

        BarCodeBuilder builder = new    BarCodeBuilder(Symbology.CODE39STANDARD, codeText);
        builder.save(strBarFolder + strImageFile);
        System.out.println("Successfully Done");

        Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(strBarFolder + strImageFile);
        BarCodeReader reader = new BarCodeReader(img, BarCodeReadType.Code39Standard);

        while(reader.read()){
            System.out.println("Code Text Found: " + reader.getCodeText());
        }
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, to get a sharper image you should use a lossless format such as PNG instead of JPG. This is also likely to make a smaller file because of the nature of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Get into the **Aspose** source code (if it's allowable) and comment out the **drawString()** method which is drawing the text to the image OR modify the bar code image by drawing a white rectangle with **fillRect()** over the text area(s) of the image.

Below is a small runnable console application I quickly whipped up that performs the latter. It is based off of the Bar Code image you provided:

```
package barcodetextcoverup;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class BarCodeTextCoverUp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        startTextCover();
    }

    private static void startTextCover() {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = "";
        while (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter the path and file name to the Bar Code image file\n"
                             + "to modify or enter quit to exit:");
            userInput = scnr.nextLine();
            if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) { break; }

            // opening a bar code image from disk
            BufferedImage src = null;
            try {
                src = ImageIO.read(new File(userInput));
                int iWidth = src.getWidth();
                int iHeight = src.getHeight();
                // Modify the image...
                Graphics2D g2 = src.createGraphics();
                g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                //Cover the text: Aspose.Demo
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 30);
                // Cover the codeText at bottom of Bar Code
                g2.fillRect((iWidth/2) - 75, iHeight - 40, 150, 35);
                g2.dispose();

                System.out.println("\nEnter a NEW path and file name for the modified Bar Code image.\n"
                                 + "You can use the same file name just change the extention to .png:");
                userInput = scnr.nextLine();
                // If nothing is supplied then the modifications are not saved.
                if (!userInput.equals("")) {
                    ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) src, "PNG", new File(userInput));
                }
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
            } catch (IOException ex) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this property:

```
builder.CodeLocation = CodeLocation.None;
```

> Setting CodeLocation to None will hide the barcode text thus creating
>   the effect of barcode without any value in it.

from Aspose support forum: https://forum.aspose.com/t/creating-2d-bar-code-using-aspose-and-merging-it-in-pdf/7265

if you want to change caption text use this property...

```
builder.Display2DText = "this is caption text";
```

By default if it's set to empty string it displays codetext.

Answer (score 0):

Read the properties of bar-code methods in the below link
http://barbecue.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sourceforge/barbecue/Barcode.html

Using the **setDrawingText**(Boolean) default method we remove the text in below bar-code

Example :

```
Barcode barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128(id);
barcode.setDrawingText(false);
BarcodeImageHandler.writePNG(barcode, new FileOutputStream(new File(file Name)));
```